# What are the basic concepts of development of multiplayer online games?

Tags: iphone

I want to develop a game for multi user can play at a time with together in iPhone, but I don't have any idea about concept of online game development.

Comment: wrong forum buddy... you probably want to ask this here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

lukya is right that this isn't a game forum but to give you an idea of what you need is:

A connection manager, this can be done easily though GameKit. Very easy to implement, heres a [tutorial](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/0/page/1) that uses GameKit to make a small chat program using Bluetooth (can be converted to wireless afaik)
Once you can connect 2 or more devices and send information then you need to work concepts such as data transfer in sync with the other play. For game dynamics look up Cocos 2d to make a simple game with boxes or whatever and look at the GKRocket/Tank (cant remem) demo on the Apple docs. This is a two player game with tanks that uses GK.

Mess with the game logic, get info passing between and build from there.
If you get stuck on a particular aspect then ask here :)